# How to get application starting and ending time in Symbian

Tags: c++, java-me, symbian

Can any one show me, how to get starting time and ending time for all applications installed on Symbian device using symbian C++ or JavaME.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody in the device keeps track of the starting and ending times.

If you want this info then you have poll it yourself - you must write a process that runs in the background and periodically polls the list of running applications. Then compare the list with previous run and log the new names and record stopping time for those that are no longer listed.

Comment: Then how to get list of running application..?

Comment: Search for RWsSession::WindowGroupList , SWindowGroupInfo ,RApaLsSession::GetAppInfo

Comment: thanks for your help, should i have to implement this in Symbian c++ or j2me. Which way is best, Because i have Started application in JavaME and i have Requirement which Will record all Applications Starting time and Closing time which we have opened. this Events should be recorded By my Application.

Comment: In that case you better start from "Hello world" and use Google to search these classes.

Comment: I don't know what you can do in JavaME. I think you might not have access to other processes as JAva is running in his own sandbox.

Comment: that's ok, Can you please say me how to implement in symbianc++, if you have any code then please send me..